# Can a high rep user nominate a user under 300 rep, during moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, election, nominations

Is it possible for a user X with enough reputation to be able to nominate some user Y with fewer than 300 reputation, during the nomination phase of moderator elections?

The wording at the bottom of the page suggests that it may be possible for others to nominate a user under 300 rep

> You must have more than 300 reputation to nominate yourself as a candidate in this election.

So, is this actually possible?

Is there a good reason for allowing people to Nominate people under 300 rep?

I already feel that there is a way to nominate another person for moderator, so that is why I ask.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I already feel that there is a way to nominate another person for moderator, so that is why I ask.

No, there isn't. People can only nominate themselves.

They cannot and **should not** nominate others.

Moderation work requires some people to invest time and effort into the site - not everyone is comfortable to do so, and getting nominated by others can put undue pressure on someone who isn't interested in the position.

So - only people who are *interested* in the position should self-nominate.

Comment: That is why the user can decline, right?  I think that some people may be willing but don't want to stick there head out unless someone says "hey it's okay, come on out!"

Comment: @Malachi - Moderation isn't something someone should be pushed into. It should be something someone wants to do.

Comment: I don't see Nominating as pushing.

Comment: @Malachi - If someone isn't motivated to nominate themselves, then how would you be sure they are motivated enough to moderate an entire site?

Comment: sounds like that should be part of the "Discussion" aspect of your answer and why you feel that people shouldn't nominate other people.

Comment: @Malachi - I think it is rather self evident. Do you nominate someone else to be mayor? No. You get people who nominate themselves (sure, they may have gotten a push, but that wouldn't be via someone else nominating them for the position). You can always **chat** to someone who you think is suitable - and nudge them towards it.

Comment: @Oded to be mayor, all you need to do is check into "city hall" enough on four square. It's automatic.